# Linked SVG Does Not Antialias in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have an SVG of a client's logo that needs to have one color scheme for the header (blue on white) and its inverse in the footer (white on blue). To reduce load, I'm using a single inline `<svg>` element with `<symbol>`, referencing it in two places using `<svg><use xlink:href="#logo"/></svg>`, and then styling each version appropriately using CSS.

So far, so good. I only have to call the SVG once and can style it differently in both places without any issues.

However, after checking this setup in IE11, I saw that the linked SVG looks terrible. It doesn't appear to be antialiasing, but only on the linked version.

I've reduced the SVG to a simplified version for this example (and to anonymize the client), but [you can see this behavior in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygs0ryce/1/) if you preview it in IE11.

Here is a screenshot of the behavior in IE11. The version on the left is the code I want, but you can see the quality degradation compared to the full SVG inline on the right.

[image: Linked SVG in IE11 on left, inline SVG in IE11 on right]

Is there any reason why only IE11 (IE9 and IE10 render this correctly) does this? I tried putting `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` and `shape-rendering="optimizeQuality"` in both `<svg>` elements and in the `<path>` element and the quality doesn't change in IE11.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The reason is a bug presumably. You could try reporting it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be working if you put the source at the top of the code.

Like so:

```
<svg style="display:none" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 90.44" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1">
<symbol id="logo">
    <defs>
        <clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="m0 67.83 432 0L432 0 0 0 0 67.83Z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,90.436933)">
        <g clip-path="url(#clipPath16)">
            <g transform="translate(25.9522,0.5186)">
                <path d="m0 0c-11.91 4.19-25.95 13.63-25.95 27.69l0 28 2.56 1.2c14.27 6.65 32.15 10.42 47.85 10.42l4.44 0 0-39.62C28.9 13.63 14.86 4.19 2.95 0L1.47-0.52 0 0ZM-21.51 52.86C-10.12 58.17 7.13 62.87 24.46 62.87l0-35.18C24.46 16.11 12.05 7.91 1.47 4.19-9.1 7.91-21.51 16.11-21.51 27.69l0 25.17z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(31.1309,54.8155)">
                <path d="M0 0C-0.02-0.01-0.05-0.02-0.07-0.03-0.05-0.02-0.02-0.01 0 0" class="s0" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(31.2388,54.8624)">
                <path d="M0 0C-0.04-0.01-0.07-0.03-0.11-0.05-0.07-0.03-0.04-0.01 0 0" class="s0" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(31.0625,54.7837)">
                <path d="M0 0C0 0 0 0-0.01 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" class="s0" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</symbol>
</svg>

<header>
<div>
    <a href="test.html"><svg viewBox="0 0 576 90.44">
        <use xlink:href="#logo"/>
    </svg></a>
</div>
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 576 90.44">
        <use xlink:href="#logo"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</header>

<div class="clear"><!-- --></div>

<footer>
    <div>
    <a href="test.html"><svg viewBox="0 0 576 90.44">
        <use xlink:href="#logo"/>
    </svg></a>
</div>
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 576 90.44">
        <use xlink:href="#logo"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Holy crap. Yeah, that did it. So bizarre, it has to be some sort of bug, but that fixes my problem right now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Holy crap indeed :)
Thanks to you as well, for pointing out the use of the <symbol> tags and linking SVG's. This will prove to be usefull to me I'm certain.